# Man sent to a desert land joins up with rebels

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

A movie I saw as a child;  the man is sent to a desert land, where there are rebels etc.  He falls in love with a girl, creates running water using the scrap he found, he's raided by the rebels.. I believe he becomes a fighter and takes it all back.

I think it was set on a planet or a desert island.. I don't remember!

Comment: About how long ago did you see it? Also when you say "desert land" do you mean a desert planet?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find it finally -- on IMDB it is ["STEEL DAWN"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094033/)  possibly one of my favorite Sci-fi post apocalyptic movies ever.

Synopsis:

> In a post-apocalyptic world, a warrior wandering through the desert comes upon a group of settlers who are being menaced by a murderous gang that is after the water they control.

Comment: Glad I could help. For future reference, the answer space here should be reserved for actually answering the question (which you do). We have a comment system for replying to users. I've edited your answer into something more in line with our model, but feel free to make further edits if you want to make any changes to it